# Can I debug my Laravel migration by writing to standard out? How?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am running a set of migrations that denormalize one of my tables.  I am running some code in one of the migrations that sets the ids in a new table based on the content of the current table.

For some reason, the id is not getting written correctly.  To debug this, I would like to echo some of the variables out to the command line when I run the migration (in development).  However, I have so far been unable to get those commands to work.

Comment: you can still do `var_dump`s inside the migrations for *debugging* and `migrate:refresh [--seed]`

Comment: Have you actually tried this?  When I run a migration with a var_dump in it, I don't see any additional output on the command line.

Comment: i do get `var_dump` output.

Comment: Hmm... well, I don't. I'd be interested if you have any theories on why.

Comment: Ah... ok.  I see now. Apparently the code with the debug statement in it wasn't getting run and I just assumed that it was being silenced somehow.  *bonk*

Comment: Trying to decide whether to delete this question, or to answer it with... "All the usual ways, just don't be a dip shirt."

Comment: just go with a *use var_dump* answer et voila ;)

Comment: Well, you're obviously not a reputation grubber, but if you want the points, go ahead and provide the answer for me to accept.  After all, you gave me the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use all the usual ways (echo, var_dump, print_r).  They will output normally to the command line in migrations.

If you suspect (as I did) that something about Laravel's migration system is silencing them, you are barking up the wrong tree.